# Add a UIImage on top of CATiledLayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, catiledlayer, cgrect

Is it possible to draw a UIImage on top of the CATiledLayer. The main idea is to note the position on the view. I have used PhotoScroller example from Apple Library and I am trying to add an UIImage on top of the tileRect. Any help will be appreciated.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    /**** Trying to add UIImage on top of CGRect rect. But not working.****/
CGRect pointRect = CGRectMake(100,100,32,32);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map-pointer32.png"];
[image drawInRect:pointRect];

// get the scale from the context by getting the current transform matrix, then asking for
// its "a" component, which is one of the two scale components. We could also ask for "d".
// This assumes (safely) that the view is being scaled equally in both dimensions.
CGFloat initialScale = CGContextGetCTM(context).a;

NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f", initialScale];
CGFloat scale = [value floatValue];

CATiledLayer *tiledLayer = (CATiledLayer *)[self layer];
CGSize tileSize = tiledLayer.tileSize;

// Even at scales lower than 100%, we are drawing into a rect in the coordinate system of the full
// image. One tile at 50% covers the width (in original image coordinates) of two tiles at 100%. 
// So at 50% we need to stretch our tiles to double the width and height; at 25% we need to stretch 
// them to quadruple the width and height; and so on.
// (Note that this means that we are drawing very blurry images as the scale gets low. At 12.5%, 
// our lowest scale, we are stretching about 6 small tiles to fill the entire original image area. 
// But this is okay, because the big blurry image we're drawing here will be scaled way down before 
// it is displayed.)
tileSize.width /= scale;
tileSize.height /= scale;

// calculate the rows and columns of tiles that intersect the rect we have been asked to draw
int firstCol = floorf(CGRectGetMinX(rect) / tileSize.width);
int lastCol = floorf((CGRectGetMaxX(rect)-1) / tileSize.width);
int firstRow = floorf(CGRectGetMinY(rect) / tileSize.height);
int lastRow = floorf((CGRectGetMaxY(rect)-1) / tileSize.height);

for (int row = firstRow; row <= lastRow; row++) {
    for (int col = firstCol; col <= lastCol; col++) {
        UIImage *tile = [self tileForScale:scale row:row col:col];
        CGRect tileRect = CGRectMake(tileSize.width * col, tileSize.height * row,
                                     tileSize.width, tileSize.height);



        // if the tile would stick outside of our bounds, we need to truncate it so as to avoid
        // stretching out the partial tiles at the right and bottom edges
        tileRect = CGRectIntersection(self.bounds, tileRect);

        [tile drawInRect:tileRect];




        if (self.annotates) {
            // [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
            CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 6.0 / scale);
            CGContextStrokeRect(context, tileRect);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best solution would be to add the image in separate view, without any catiledlayer.
You can add an empty view, and add the view with the the catiledlayer an the uiimageview to that view.